# getting a segmentation fault with RSA_public_encrypt

Tags: c, openssl, rsa

Here's my code:

```
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
        char publicKey[] = "-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n"\
"MIIBCgKCAQEAqBa0jeqfHO8CFZuHyN5WgdTd3uThkU/I9lR+bb2R9khVU1tYhiyL\n"\
"Gfnm051K0039gCBAz9S7HHO2lqR/B1kiEGwBzg83N3tL2UzQXXbpxJz0b7vV8rXZ\n"\
"fB9j+FCAtD5znittXRjWrNqlEyJyxK+PuxNF3uPGWSjkYtRKv2f5HCXsfRJah40w\n"\
"5zU+OKZsZMrSSxweYN9Jwc++oMaSPCsGKog6NPbkbcTK8Akveof8v5rpG50I/zcQ\n"\
"9dCD69qJcmhm4ai4fAZFJlsFH2HmxV6DERFs3TNyzGlSQ1gd/XLER7U9nlrOUT87\n"\
"mXreUIXSkAFdCrlHXHOzj0eodfN8IfHjnQIDAQAB\n"\
"-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n";
    char plaintext[] = "enp6";

    // base64 decode plaintext
    EVP_DecodeBlock(plaintext, plaintext, strlen(plaintext));

    BIO* bo = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    BIO_write(bo, publicKey, strlen(publicKey));
    EVP_PKEY* pkey = 0;
    PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY(bo, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    BIO_free(bo);
    RSA* rsa = EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA(pkey);
    char ciphertext[RSA_size(rsa)];

    RSA_public_encrypt(strlen(plaintext), plaintext, ciphertext, rsa, RSA_NO_PADDING);
    printf("%d\n", (int) strlen(ciphertext));
}
```

I'm trying to run it by doing `gcc -x c test2.c -lcrypto && ./a.out`. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is it really allowed to use the same buffer (`plaintext[]`) for source and destination of `EVP_DecodeBlock`? Also, is `strlen(plaintext);` still valid after that? `EVP_DecodeBlock` returns the length of the decoded data, so shouldn't you be using that as the length of the plaintext after decoding?

Comment: Also, `strlen(ciphertext);` does not seem to be correct because `ciphertext` is not a null-terminated string.

Comment: The backslashes on end of line are redundant, as adjacent string literals are concatenated anyway. You would use that if you weren't using quotes for every line

Comment: @IanAbbott The documentation doesn't say whether EVP_DecodeBlock needs separate source and destination, unfortunately. So it's either time to dive into the source code, or defensively use different buffers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code contains several mistakes. The direct cause of the segfault is the fact that the variable `pkey` is never assigned any value after initializing it with `0`. `EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA(pkey)` segfaults as a consequence. You probably intended to do

```
EVP_PKEY *pkey = PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY(bo, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

However, with the PEM that you posted, that will not work. The header of the PEM indicates that this is an RSA key stored in "traditional" format. `PEM_read_bio_RSAPublicKey` is capable of reading such keys:

```
RSA *rsa = PEM_read_bio_RSAPublicKey(bo, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Then your choice of `RSA_NO_PADDING` when invoking `RSA_public_encrypt` is not right. In order to use that, the plaintext must be the exact same length as the key size. You could try using `RSA_PKCS1_PADDING` instead.

Finally, like mentioned in the comment section as well, using `strlen` on cipher text is incorrect, because it is not a 0-terminated string.

In general, you should check all return values for all OpenSSL functions invoked, to see when/if something went wrong.

Comment: adding on to this, the size of ciphertext is `sizeof ciphertext`. OP seems unaware that RSA encryption occurs in blocks of the same size as the key length

Comment: Yes, although I am not sure whether `sizeof` would work in this case due to the way the array is declared. But additionally, as [the man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/RSA_public_encrypt.html) states: "RSA_public_encrypt() returns the size of the encrypted data (i.e., RSA_size(rsa)).". :-)

Comment: @M.M well I tried it and `sizeof` does appear to work on VLAs -- I never knew.

Comment: I tried your suggestions and I'm still getting a segmentation fault: https://pastebin.com/8r0T59QA  . Here it is with the me checking the return values and using `ERR_error_string` when there's an error (I'm not getting any errors): https://pastebin.com/iwdA3aDB

Comment: You do not need the `EVP_PKEY` anymore, you can remove that line. Then you are invoking `PEM_read_bio_RSAPublicKey` on `bo` after invoking `BIO_free` on it, which will fail. First read, then free the bio. The error checking looks good to me though. When running your current code, I do see an error message `error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line` after trying to read that `EVP_PKEY` (which is cryptic, but means that it does not recognize the header. That is because it does not expect the RSA header).